# Error al imprimir un formulario en excel

Tags: visual-studio

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente problema: 
**Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC** en la siguiente linea:

```
ws.cells(8, 7).Value = FA_Elaborated.Text
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 Private Sub ImprimirFormulario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
 Handles 
  ImprimirFormulario.Click
 'Try

Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
app.UserControl = True
Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\FormularioFA\Formato\FA_Formulario.xlsx")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
Dim ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
app.Visible = True
app.UserControl = True
ws.cells(8, 7).Value = FA_Elaborated.Text
ws.cells(9, 7).Value = ID_Employee.Text
ws.cells(10, 7).Value = Work_Shift.Text
ws.cells(11, 7).Value = ID_FA.Text
ws.cells(12, 7).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
ws.cells(17, 3).Value = Test_Station.Text
ws.cells(19, 3).Value = Failure_Reported.Text
ws.cells(23, 5).Value = Component_Location.Text
ws.cells(24, 5).Value = Supplier.Text
ws.cells(25, 5).Value = Supplier_SerialNumber.Text
ws.cells(26, 5).Value = Supplier_PartNumber.Text
ws.cells(27, 5).Value = DateCode.Text
ws.cells(31, 5).Value = SerialNumber_82Level.Text
ws.cells(32, 5).Value = PartNumber_82Level.Text
ws.cells(36, 5).Value = Assembly_SerialNumber.Text
ws.cells(37, 5).Value = Assembly_PartNumber.Text
ws.cells(50, 3).Value = Failure_Mode.Text
ws.cells(59, 3).Value = Debug_Steps.Text
ws.cells(96, 2).Value = Failure_Mode.Text

Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetDataObject(PictureBox2.Image)
ws.cells(74, 2).select
ws.paste

FA_Elaborated.Text = ""
ID_Employee.Text = ""
Work_Shift.Text = Nothing
ID_FA.Text = ID_FA.Text + 1
Test_Station.Text = ""
Failure_Reported.Text = ""
Component_Location.Text = ""
Supplier.Text = ""
Supplier_SerialNumber.Text = ""
Supplier_PartNumber.Text = ""
DateCode.Text = ""
SerialNumber_82Level.Text = ""
PartNumber_82Level.Text = ""
Assembly_PartNumber.Text = ""
Assembly_SerialNumber.Text = ""
Failure_Mode.Text = ""
Debug_Steps.Text = ""
Conclution.Text = ""
PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
FA_Elaborated.Focus()
    'Catch ex As Exception
'   MsgBox(ex.Message)
'End Try
End Sub
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Saludos...

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `FA_Elaborated.Text`? Puede que debas antepornerle una comilla simple.

Comment: @RogerTorné el valor que tiene `FA_Elaborated.Text` es una cadena de caracteres, aunque ponga comilla simple sigue apareciendo el error.

Comment: Pueden ser mil cosas, pero prueba esto antes de mirar otras soluciones: abres el xslx y sin hacer cambios, lo guardas, luego asignas los valores. No sea que Excel lo esté marcando como archivo corrupto

Comment: @RogerTorné Ya hice eso y sigue persientiendo el error

Comment: Si eliminas esa línea `ws.cells(8, 7).Value = FA_Elaborated.Text` ¿el resto no da problemas?

Comment: @RogerTorné Ya lo solucione

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione quitando el `value`de `ws.cells(8, 7).Value` quedando de la siguiente manera: `ws.cells(8, 7) = FA_Elaborated.Text` y asi en todas las demas lineas

quedando el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
     Private Sub ImprimirFormulario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
     ImprimirFormulario.Click
    'Try

    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Add("C:\FormularioFA\Formato\FA_Formulario.xlsx")
    Dim ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    app.Visible = True
    app.UserControl = True

    ws.cells(8, 7) = FA_Elaborated.Text
    ws.cells(9, 7) = ID_Employee.Text
    ws.cells(10, 7) = Work_Shift.Text
    ws.cells(11, 7) = ID_FA.Text
    ws.cells(12, 7) = DateTimePicker1.Value
    ws.cells(17, 3) = Test_Station.Text
    ws.cells(19, 3) = Failure_Reported.Text
    ws.cells(23, 5) = Component_Location.Text
    ws.cells(24, 5) = Supplier.Text
    ws.cells(25, 5) = Supplier_SerialNumber.Text
    ws.cells(26, 5) = Supplier_PartNumber.Text
    ws.cells(27, 5) = DateCode.Text
    ws.cells(31, 5) = SerialNumber_82Level.Text
    ws.cells(32, 5) = PartNumber_82Level.Text
    ws.cells(36, 5) = Assembly_SerialNumber.Text
    ws.cells(37, 5) = Assembly_PartNumber.Text
    ws.cells(50, 3) = Failure_Mode.Text
    ws.cells(59, 3) = Debug_Steps.Text
    ws.cells(96, 2) = Failure_Mode.Text

    Clipboard.Clear()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(PictureBox2.Image)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    ws.cells(74, 2).select
    ws.paste
    ws.cells(8, 7).select
    app.SaveWorkspace("C:\FormularioFA\Capturas\" & Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".xlsx")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    FA_Elaborated.Text = ""
    ID_Employee.Text = ""
    Work_Shift.Text = Nothing
    ID_FA.Text = ID_FA.Text + 1
    Test_Station.Text = ""
    Failure_Reported.Text = ""
    Component_Location.Text = ""
    Supplier.Text = ""
    Supplier_SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Supplier_PartNumber.Text = ""
    DateCode.Text = ""
    SerialNumber_82Level.Text = ""
    PartNumber_82Level.Text = ""
    Assembly_PartNumber.Text = ""
    Assembly_SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Failure_Mode.Text = ""
    Debug_Steps.Text = ""
    Conclution.Text = ""
    PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
    FA_Elaborated.Focus()
        'Catch ex As Exception
    '   MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos...